# Extract house and road using image Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, image-segmentation

where I live does not have gis data, only images from google earth, so I want to take advantage of this image to build gis data,it is local's road, river and house. I am a beginner with this job. I using "Iso cluster Unsupervised Classification" tool in Arcgis. This is results i get.
[image]

Some houses and water are the same color.
Are there any other methods to improve the interpretation results?

Comment: ArcScan? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/what-is-arcscan-.htm

Comment: @Mapperz it's helpful to me ,,thanks